# How to link auth after unlinking the only provider?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an anonymous account and then it links with email & password. Then I unlink the provider. Everything works fine. But when I try to link the account with another email & password, Firebase returns error and ask for authentication.

I know that Firebase requires recent authentication for sensitive operation. But as the account has unlink its only provider, it should return into an anonymous account again and does not have a password for authentication. How can I provide an authentication to Firebase? If I call SignInAnonymouslyAsync again in order to provide the authentication, will Firebase create another new user with a new User ID in database?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.